# rendering template html via backbone view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I have a simple page that contains a 3 step wizard.  Basically, the user fills out a textbox, clicks next, which loads the next form field.

I have setup all the HTML inside a template and use that template in a backbone view.

The problem is, backbone isn't rendering the HTML inside the template. I just get a blank screen.

Here is my template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="assessmentTitleTemplate">

    <div id="titleDiv">
        <label for="title">Title:</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" />
    </div>

    <div id="choicesDiv" style="display: none;">
        <label for="choices">Choices:</label><input type="text" />
    </div>

    <div id="typeDiv" style="display: none;">
        <label for="types">Types:</label>
        <select name="type">
            <option>red</option>
            <option>blue</option>
            <option>green</option>
        </select>
    </div>

   <div id="directionControl">       
        <input type="button" value="Prev" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Next" />
    </div>

</script>
```

This is my backbone javascript code:

```
"use strict";

var titleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'title',
    template: _.template($('#assessmentTitleTemplate').html()),

    events: {
        'click .next': 'saveProceedNext',
        'click .prev': 'ProceedPrev'

    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.render;
    },

    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    saveProceedNext: function() {
        this.$('#titleDiv').hide();
        this.$('#choicesDiv').show();
    },

    ProceedPrev: function() {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, but you're missing a couple of parens in your `initialize` body:

```
initialize : function () {
    this.render();  // it was this.render; before
}
```

Your code isn't invoking the function.

Also, you're missing `class` tags for your buttons, or else they won't work when clicked. Adding this will make them work:

```
<input type="button" value="Prev" class="prev" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Next" class="next" />
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eZD9j/).

Comment: thanks, that worked, I also didn't have the line view = new titleView...or the empty div to put it in.

Comment: As a minor note, I'd recommend not rendering within your `initialize` function. It makes coordinating with other objects (like views) tricky, and makes it much more difficult to test.

Comment: Yeah, it's far better having `initialize` and `render` decoupled. From my experience, working with the `el` attribute on instantiation is a bad practice (I mean, doing this: `new Backbone.View({ el : $("...") });`) unless it's the very main view or something special.